# Store Website User Experience Points With Facebook Login

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, authentication, web

My goal is to create something like 1Up.com has where website viewers gain Experience Points for viewing articles, writing comments, etc on my website.

Check out the blue bar at the top of 1Up: [1up.com](http://www.1up.com/)

I want users to be able to login through Facebook rather than create an account specifically for my website. The Facebook login stuff I can figure out, I'm just not sure how to best approach storing some information to that users account (such as # of experience points) and then accessing this and displaying it back to them on the page.

I realize this is a pretty wide open question and I'm not expecting any super specific responses, but anything that get's me pointed in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a database. Databases make the world go round. Look into creating a mySQL database.